# Prolog implementation of "Which answer in this list is the correct answer to this question?"

Tags: prolog, logic

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217248/which-answer-in-this-list-is-the-correct-answer-to-this-question) post on Math Exchange, asking for the solution to the following logic puzzle:

> Which answer in this list is the correct answer to *this* question?
>
> 1. All of the below.
> 2. None of the below.
> 3. All of the above.
> 4. One of the above.
> 5. None of the above.
> 6. None of the above.

I know that the answer is 5, but because I am trying to learn Prolog I'd like to find a way for Prolog to give me the answer.
I tried to use the following knowledge base to encode the information given in the puzzle:

```
answer(1) :- answer(2),answer(3),answer(4),answer(5),answer(6).
answer(2) :- \+answer(3), \+answer(4), \+answer(5), \+answer(6).
answer(3) :- answer(1), answer(2).
answer(4) :- answer(1); answer(2); answer(3).
answer(5) :- \+answer(1), \+answer(2), \+answer(3), \+answer(4).
answer(6) :- \+answer(1), \+answer(2), \+answer(3), \+answer(4), \+answer(5).
```

However, when trying to evaluate

```
?- answer(X).
```

I run into a infinite recursion (which is to be expected when naively substituting the predicates).

1. Is there a way to solve this specific puzzle with Prolog? <sup>1</sup>
2. More generally, how can I know ahead of time when a logic puzzle is well suited for Prolog?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Yes, I know Prolog is turing complete, so encoding the problem into a turing machine and iterating all the possible solutions (like is done in the first answer to the Math exchange post) is of course a possibility but I'm looking for the "canonical" way of solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a good use of [library(clpb)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpb) for defining and solving a direct solution using boolean variables:

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).

solve(Answer) :- 
    Options = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6],
    sat(*([
        (A1 =:= (A2 * A3 * A4 * A5 * A6)),
        (A2 =:= (~A3 * ~A4 * ~A5 * ~A6)),
        (A3 =:= (A1 * A2)),
        (A4 =:= (card([1], [A1, A2, A3]))),
        (A5 =:= (~A1 * ~A2 * ~A3 * ~A4)),
        (A6 =:= ( ~A1 * ~A2 * ~A3 * ~A4 * ~A5))
    ])),
    labeling(Options),
    nth1(Answer, Options, 1).
```

Taking the options provided as variables `A1` through `A6`, each of the individual expressions must hold, so they are made a conjunction with `*(Exprs)`. Most of the options are as listed in the question, just converted to the CLP(B) forms. `A4` uses the cardinality constraint, meaning "only one of" the listed options can be true. After running the options through `labeling` and picking out the answer from the options that is set to 1, the result is as expected:

```
?- solve(Answer).
Answer = 5 ;
false.
```

Comment: To more directly address the second part of the question asked: I think the best way to size up if a puzzle suited for Prolog or any other language is to determine how easy it is to model the puzzle using that particular tool. Here it seemed to fit a Prolog feature really well, it was simple and concise, but there are certainly plenty of other tools that can accomplish the task. I've also seen assignment problems solved with iterative solutions because they are more readable and maintainable, even if they are slower at the end of the day.